# How to get OpenGL working on Dell M3800?

Tags: opengl

I have a Dell M3800 laptop. It has Intel HD Graphics integrated along with nVidia K1100M Graphics Card. It appears OpenGL doesn't run on my laptop although I am not sure that is the case.

I am currently in a programming class at college and the professor gave us some programs that use OpenGL that do not run on my M3800. They do however run just fine on my Microsoft Surface Pro 4. On my Surface Pro 4 I also created a program using OpenGL graphics and runs fine on the Surface Pro, runs fine on my brothers desktop, but does not run on my M3800 throwing errors such as not being able to run certain OpenGL libraries.

I opened my nVidia Control Panel but it is empty. Can anybody help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: Installing the Nvidia drivers will enable OpenGL support,  it won’t be a recent version, due to the age of your card.  What version of OpenGL are you trying to use.  You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: The only NVidia card listed as a 3800M is one of the Quadro FX cards, capable of OpenGL 3.3 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#Quadro_FX_(x800M)_series

Comment: I actually just edited the information because I wrote it down slightly wrong. My laptop is a Dell M3800 and I accidentally wrote that number down instead of the actual graphics card model. The graphics card I have is a K1100M. I also am unsure of what version of OpenGL I am using as I am actually using VTK libraries which use OpenGL. I looked through documentation and couldn't find the answer so I posted on another forum to find that out and will let you know once I know. Thanks,

Comment: Then google "K1100M opengl version" which gives "The NVIDIA Quadro K1100M is a DirectX 11 and OpenGL 4.3 compatible graphics card for mobile workstations." Just installing the correct NVidia drivers should be enough. You didn't tell us what OS, but Nvidia's site should have everything you need.

Comment: I figured out at least a temporary fix. It appears that the problem is the nVidia Optimus software. This software automatically switches between the integrated intel graphics and the nVidia graphics card depending on the graphics load of the computer. So for the programs experiencing problems (Qt Creator and my personally created programs) I right click on the app, open file location, right click on desired shortcut, run with graphics processor, click on the nVidia processor option and I no longer have any troubles.